# Can powershell wait until IE is DOM ready?

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I'm currently writing a script and I'm using

```
while($IE.busy) {Start-Sleep 1}
```

to wait for the page to be ready.

Once the page is ready my script fills out and submits a form. I've been running into problems because (I think) IE reports that it's done when the page is loaded but before the document has been rendered (which causes the script to error out). My current workaround is to add a 4 second wait time after the page loads but I'd feel more comfortable with a method that isn't time based if possible.

Comment: I'm going to assume you're using the `InternetExlporer.Application` COM object? If so, you probably will not be able to subscribe for events, because it's not a .NET object. If it were a .NET object, you could use `Register-ObjectEvent` to hook up an event handler.

Comment: Correct, I'm using the IE COM object. So I guess increasing the wait to a time I think is safe is the only option?

Comment: As far as I know, yeah the time-based checking is your best bet. If, after a certain period of time (eg. 5 minutes), you want to stop checking, you can use a `break` statement inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Wait, are you saying I'm able to check if the DOM is ready? Right now I'm not checking at all. I'm just waiting until IE isn't busy (which I think only captures network activity) then trying to wait a safe amount of time before I begin interacting with the DOM.

Am I able to check if the DOM is ready before interacting with it? I'm fine with putting this on a timer. My problem was that I didn't know I could even check it, the code I had on a timer was the code that actually interacts with the page (fills out a form) and obviously fails if the DOM isn't ready yet.

Comment: I am struggling with same sort of issue. My current solution relies on repeatedly polling the the document for a particular element and checking its content e.g. `$htmlTag = ($ie.Document).getElementsByTagName("HTML")` `$innerHTML = ($htmlTag | Select-Object -ExpandProperty innerHTML)`

Comment: Apologies - the previous comment was posted in haste and is incomplete. Once I have the innerHtml, I then parse it looking for a particular element which is only present when the page is rendered. Once this is found, I know page is fully loaded. Messy, but it has been reliable so far. I cannot see any other way that IE would 'know' when the page was completely rendered.

Comment: Thanks. you should post this as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer. It might not be ideal, but it does what needs to be done and is more reliable than the arbitrary wait time I'm currently using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how I do this.

Step 1 - Identify a web page element that only appears once the page is fully rendered. I did this using the Chrome developer tools 'Elements' view which shows the DOM view.

Step 2 - Establish a wait loop in the script which polls for the existence of the element or the value of text inside that element.

```
# Element ID to check for in DOM
$elementID = "systemmessage"

# Text to match in elemend
$elementMatchText = "logged in"

# Timeout
$timeoutMilliseconds = 5000

$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"

# optional
$ie.Visible = $true

$ie.Navigate2("http://somewebpage")
$timeStart = Get-Date
$exitFlag = $false

do {

    sleep -milliseconds 100

    if ( $ie.ReadyState -eq 4 ) {

        $elementText = (($ie.Document).getElementByID($elementID )).innerText
        $elementMatch = $elementText -match $elementMatchText

        if ( $elementMatch ) { $loadTime = (Get-Date).subtract($timeStart) }

    }

    $timeout = ((Get-Date).subtract($timeStart)).TotalMilliseconds -gt $timeoutMilliseconds
    $exitFlag = $elementMatch -or $timeout

} until ( $exitFlag )

Write-Host "Match element found: $elementMatch"
Write-Host "Timeout: $timeout"
Write-Host "Load Time: $loadTime"
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this thread really helpful and ended up coming up with a slightly different solution. I am pretty new to powershell so hopefully I didn't make a hash of it but this worked really well for me.

I used a "while" statement so that my condition would loop while true:

```
while($ie.document.body.outerHTML -notMatch "<input type=`"submit`" value=`"Continue`">") {start-sleep -m 100};
```

In this case I was matching against a portion of the "outerHTML" part of the body. As long as I don't match the specified text the script will wait and continue to loop the match check.

I like this solution as I could do it in more or less one line of code and I like to keep things compact where possible. Hopefully this is helpful to someone else. Like the OP I found ie.readystate to be very finnicky/unreliable but I really didn't want to just put a static sleep timer in.

Also, while Chrome is an excellent way to break a page down. You can also print to the console window once you have IE running programmatically by simply running:

```
$ie.document.body
```

You can dig through visually and then filter down to the section you want which should speed up your matching (I would guess), which is what I did in my code example above.

The only other thing I will note... I think -match uses  "regex" because I had to use the tick mark (ex. `  ) to escape the quotes that were part of the string I was matching.

Cheers!

Here is a good reference on "while" logic:
http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/logic-using-loops/