# login into a web page using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to log on to a web page with credentials from the get-credential window. But I am getting error- `Property 'Value' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.`I have provided my powershell source code here..

```
$url = "ameriprisestage.service-now.com/"
$cred = Get-Credential 
$username = $cred.username
$username = $username.Replace("\", "")
$password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().password
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url); 
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4 -or $ie.Busy)
{
    start-sleep -milliseconds 100
}
 #$uname=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") 
#$unameBox=$uname | where { $_.name -eq "user_name" }
$unameBox=$ie.Document.getElementById("user_name")
$unameBox.value = $username
$pass=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | ? { $_.id -eq "user_password" }
$pass.value = $password
$pass.select
$buttn=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button") | ? { $_.id -eq "sysverb_login" }
$buttn.click()
while($ie.busy) {
Start-sleep 1;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the web page is not fully rendered by the time you call `getElementsByTagName`. Just because IE reports that it is no longer busy does not mean any/all page load scripts have completed. Might be worth coding a loop to wait until this step is successful.

Comment: i tried with `getelementById' too.Not working

Comment: My point is that the element may not be there to find. Try inserting a `start-sleep -seconds 60` before querying the DOM. This should give the page time to render. If it still fails then either you are looking for elements that don't exist, or using the wrong syntax.

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510779/can-powershell-wait-until-ie-is-dom-ready/22623348#22623348

Comment: It is not working.I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple  windows in the web page. Try to redirect it to the relevant window.

```
cd HKCU:\"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
set-itemproperty . ProxyEnable 1
$url = "https://ameriprisestage.service-now.com/"
#function call 

#$cred = Get-Credential 
$username = "asset_tester02"
$username = "asset_tester02"
$password = "tester02"
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url); 
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
    Start-Sleep 1; 
} 

$usr=$ie.document.getElementbyID("gsft_main").contentWindow.document.getElementbyID("user_name").value=$username
$pass=$ie.document.getElementbyID("gsft_main").contentWindow.document.getElementById("user_password").value= $password
$buttn=$ie.document.getElementbyID("gsft_main").contentWindow.document.getElementById("sysverb_login").click()
```