# Having trouble getting powershell to pick the radio button

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

I am trying to get the powershell script to open up internet explorer which does and go to a website and click a radio button. The errors that i receive tell me that the line with the getElementsByTagName. It also says I can't call a method on a null-valued expression for all of the lines below and including getElementsByTagName

```
$ie = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("hidden")
$ie.visible = $true



$doc = $ie.documentElement
$myradio = $doc.getElementsByTagName('radio')|?{$_.type -eq 'radio' -and $_.name -eq 'export'}

$x = 2 #specific radio button
$myradio.setActive()
$myradio.click()
```

Comment: Are you [waiting for the page to render](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510779/can-powershell-wait-until-ie-is-dom-ready)?

Comment: Can you give the URL ?

Comment: I can't give out the URL due to company policy, You can use this site here for testing, which its radio buttons are setup the same way http://webforms2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/testsuite/021.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out so for me I had to start the $ie part first and work my way down with it. **Powershell will not pick up COM objects if IE is not open**. Once that part got figured out everything worked like a charm.

```
#gathers COm Objects for IE
$ie = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application;
#Opens IE and navigates to the site
$ie.visible = $true;

foreach($s in $site){
$sName = $s.ServerName
$sLink = $s.Link
"`n"

$url = $site+$results

$ie.navigate($s.Link);

#sleeps for a second
    while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
    { 
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; 
    } 

#gets export button radio and clicks it
$ie.document.getElementById('exp').click();

#sleeps for another second for page to load
    while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
    { 
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; 
    } 

#Clicks search button for results page
$button = $ie.Document.getElementsByName('search') | Where-Object {$_.type -eq "button"}
$button.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

So using the URL you provided as a test, this appears to work for selecting the first radio button for favourite colour:

```
$ie = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("http://webforms2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/testsuite/021.html")
$ie.visible = $true

$doc = $ie.Document
$radioButtons = $doc.getElementsByTagName('input') | Where-Object {$_.type -eq 'radio' -and $_.name -eq 'favColor1'}

$x = 0 #specific radio button
$radioButtons[$x].setActive()
$radioButtons[$x].click()
```

`$ie.documentElement` doesn't seem to exist, hence why you get the null valued exception, you need `$ie.document` instead.

Next, you need an array of radio buttons to select from and the tag name you need to use is input in this example, you then need to use the $x variable to index into the array of radio buttons to choose which one to click.