# Why document object is null-value in my powershell script?

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I want to use powershell to automate a web download request. But I got some errors that I can't fix.

```bsh
$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("http://10.8.140.232/KPIReport/Admin/Login.aspx")
$usr_name = $ie.document.getElementById('TextBoxAccount')
$pwd = $ie.document.getElementById('TextBoxPassword')
$login_button = $ie.document.getElementById('ButtonLogin')
```

the first 3 lines can run successfully.

but from line 4, error occurs.

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:1
+ $usr_name = $ie.document.getElementById("TextBoxAccount")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

And $ie.document return null in command line.

and by the way. all the element id are existed in source html code.

I don't what happens here.

thanks for your help.

Comment: `Navigate` returns before the dom has been fully loaded, insert a `Start-Sleep 1` after Navigate and it'll probably work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can powershell wait until IE is DOM ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510779/can-powershell-wait-until-ie-is-dom-ready)

Comment: I recommend adding `Do {Sleep 1} While ($ie.busy)` instead of `Start-Sleep 1`. It guarantees that `$ie` has a second to start the non-blocking `Navigate` method, and it continues to sleep until Internet Explorer is done with the request and the document is rendered, which will frequently take more than 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment above, the error is caused by the DOM hasn't been fully loaded. I use `While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}` after `$ie.Navigate`. You could try to add it in your code.