# Powershell - IE11 - Apex - Automated Dropdown Selection

Tags: oracle, powershell, internet-explorer-11, dropdown, apex

I am trying to automate some tasks for an existing website written using Oracle Apex via PowerShell. There is a dropdown for States and when a state is selected the data needs to change accordingly. I am able to select the desired state and fire the "OnChange" Event successfully but it does not change the data like a Manual Selection of the Dropdown option would. Could someone please assist how I can using PowerShell get the same result as a Manual Selection.

Here is the sample of the Dropdown box.

```
<select  id="All_STATE" name="All_STATE" class="selectlist apex-item-select" size="1" >
   <option value="" selected="selected" >- Please Select -</option>
   <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
   <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
   <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
</select>
```

Here is powershell code I am trying to use

```
$statecontrol = $null
$statecontrol = $ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("All_STATE")
($statecontrol | where {$_.value -eq "Texas"}).Selected = $true
$statecontrol.FireEvent("OnChange")
```

I found these functions under JavaScript which may be relevant but can't be sure, I don't know APEX. I don't think I can share the whole JavaScript here cause its proprietary.

```
function(){ apex.widget.selectList("#All_STATE",{`code here`});})();

function(){ apex.jQuery('#List').interactiveReport.interactiveReport({`code here`});})();

{"triggeringElementType":"ITEM","triggeringElement":"All_STATE","bindType":"bind","bindEventType":"change","anyActionsFireOnInit":false,actionList:`code here`
```

Comment: I don’t see one bit of powershell. How are we supposed to be able to help with it?

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the post with the PowerShell Code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I created a simple example to achieve your requirements, and I think your issue is mainly the loading situation of the automated page, a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57312076/why-document-object-is-null-value-in-my-powershell-script).

This is my test, and it works well:

Page code:

```
<select id="All_STATE" name="All_STATE" class="selectlist&#x20;apex-item-select" size="1" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- Please Select -</option>
        <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
        <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
        <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
    </select>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            alert('some script code here');
        }
    </script>
```

powershell code:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("<your website url>")
While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}
$statecontrol = $ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("All_STATE")
($statecontrol | where {$_.value -eq "Texas"}).Selected = $true
$statecontrol.FireEvent("OnChange")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hello Xudong Peng, I can't make any changes to the HTML code. Since that is from an existing Website I am using. That is why I have mentioned the APEX Java function, I thought could be useful

Comment: Well, if this is the case, I think it can only implement selection options but can not trigger the `onchange` event. And I don’t know much about Oracle Apex, I’m afraid I can’t give good advice.